# シェルスクリプト データーの並び替え

Tags: bash

例えば「あ[1]、い[2]、う[3]、え[4]、お[5]」といったデーターの配列があるとします。
そこで、例えば「う」を指定したのならば「う」から開始してどんどん右へソートしていき、一番右に来たら最初から折り返し、あから再度ソートします。
つまり、
入力データーが「あ、い、う、え、お」
並び替えを開始するデーターを「う」
とすると
「う、え、お、あ、い」
と返すようにしたいです。
また、スクリプトは極端に実行速度が遅くならない限り、できるだけ簡潔なものが好ましいです。

追記です。 
並び替えを開始するデーターを指定するのは配列番号でも構いません。 
文字列ではなく配列番号で指定したほうが実行速度が早くなるか簡潔になるのであればそちらのほうが好ましいです。（つまり「う」というデーターではなく３を指定）

Comment: 「データーの配列」とは何でしょうか？ [bashの配列](https://qiita.com/b4b4r07/items/e56a8e3471fb45df2f59)ですか？ 「どんどん右へソートしていき」とは何でしょうか？ [ソート](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88)という語は正しい意味で使われていますか？ ちなみに`data`は`-er`や`-or`で終わらないため伸ばさず **データ** ですよ。

Comment: ソート対象の配列がどのようなものなのかが分かりません。ある名前の配列の中身が"あ[1]"とか"い[2]"になっているのでしょうか？　それとも"あ"とか"い"とかになっていて"[1]"の部分はその配列の添字でしょうか？　はたまた"あ"という名前の要素数1の配列や"い"という名前の要素数2の配列があるのでしょうか？

Comment: ２番目です。 ㅤ  ㅤ  ㅤ  ㅤ  ㅤ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「あ、い、う、え、お」では辞書順になっていて分かりづらいかと思いましたので、入力を `z b x h j g` に変更しています。なお、エラーチェックはしていませんので、`start` 変数に 0 以下の値を入れるとエラーになります。

```
#!/bin/bash

##declare -a arr=(あ い う え お)
declare -a arr=(z b x h j g)
declare -i start=3

: $((start--))
declare -a first=("${arr[@]:$start:${#arr[@]}}")
declare -a last=("${arr[@]:0:$start}")

IFS=$'\n'
declare -a sorted=($(sort <<<"${first[*]}") $(sort <<<"${last[*]}"))
echo "${sorted[@]}"
```

**実行結果**

```
g h j x b z
```

余談になりますが、GNU awk version 4.0 以降であれば、以下の様にもできます。ただし、入力と出力は文字列になりますが。

```
$ gawk -V
GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 4.0.1, GNU MP 6.1.2)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2016 Free Software Foundation.

$ echo 'z,b,x,h,j,g' | gawk -ijoin -vRS=',' -vSTART=3 '
    NR<START{d1[i++]=$1} NR>=START{d2[j++]=$1}
  END{
    asort(d1);asort(d2)
    printf("%s%s%s\n", join(d2,1,NR-START+1,RS),
      (START>1?RS:""), join(d1,1,START-1,RS))
  }'

 => g,h,j,x,b,z
```

Comment: ご回答有り難うございます。このスクリプトで自分のしたいことは実現できたのでこれでもいいのですが、これだと何故か半角の順番に並んでない文字が正常に並び替えされないのですが何故そうなるのでしょうか？その例にある「z b x h j g」で３を指定したなら結果は「x h j g z」となるはずです。また、「あ か ぬ え も 」のように全角で順番通りでないものや「1 2 3 4 5」や「a b c d e」のような半角でも順番通りに並んでいるものは正常に並び替えが行われました。